# how to prevent possible javascript memory hogging from crashing a browser

Tags: javascript, performance, while-loop

Especially when using while loops scenarios can arise where javascript gets stuck in a continuous loop that can crash the browser.

I usually handle this possibility by using a variable to count the number of while executions and break the while after a certain time.

While the browser no longer crashes it can still slow things down considerably.

Is there a more efficient way of handling this possibility?

Comment: Modern browsers won't let this block the whole browser for a long amount of time. They tell the user "a script seems to be stuck, click here to kill it" or something like that.

Comment: What's your scenario? Just a big amount of work that needs to be done in the browser? Or a mistake in the JS code?

Comment: @thejh Yes, but it is a very ugly error and can effect outer tabs. The scenario is basically just a big amount of work needed to be done by the browser, and it works out fine 99% percent of the time but who wants an ugly crash if it can be avoided.

Comment: Why "ugly crash"? A few seconds of waiting and then clicking "stop" or so don't fit my definition of an "ugly crash".

Comment: @thejh I guess its a question of definitions of ugly then :). I would still like to know if there is a better way to kill then the one I am using.  If only for pure curiosities sake.

Comment: What is the real issue? Is your code written incorrectly, such that it loops forever when it shouldn't? Or is your issue that you have a finite, but possibly very large (in elapsed time, cpu time, or memory) piece of work to do that you don't want to hang the UI thread?

Comment: @PaulGrime option 2 is correct, finite but possibly very large.

Comment: Can you use web workers? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_worker

Comment: @PaulGrime defiantly and interesting solution

Comment: @thejh A heads up for Chrome. If you choose to kill the script when the browser requests, it does not fail gracefully, but sends you to a browser crash screen.